# Disable edit mode for Power BI Embedded report

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have created a native app and set the permissions in Azure Active Directory to view only, and I use that to expose a report with Power BI Embedded (using the C# SDK). However, it's relatively simple to edit the JavaScript to put the report in edit mode, thereby exposing the underlying data. Is there any way to prevent the report from being edited when using Power BI Embedded, or alternatively, to ensure that only allowed data is shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the editing of the report can be overridden if modifying the JS code, that user won't be able to save or modify the report itself since the EmbedToken granted should be without a Write permission.

When creating the EmbedToken you, as the report owner, declare what abilities you grant the user on that specific report. If you didn't give the users Write access, all they can do is purely local by modifying JS.

This is defined as the `accessLevel` in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetoken

If the issue is the data access, you can achieve this by using Embedded Row-Level-Security (RLS). The steps are given in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-bi/developer/embedded-row-level-security

Under Modeling (in Power BI Desktop), select Manage Roles

1. Select the table you want to filter on, and type the DAX expression to filter on, e.g. `[City State] = "Sparta"`.
2. Give the role a name, say Spartan, and add any other filters you need. Click Save. You can select View as Roles to ensure that the data is appropriately filtered.
3. In your code, modify your token request to include a username, role and dataset. You might change it from something like `var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");` to something like `var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest("view", null, identities: new List<EffectiveIdentity> { new EffectiveIdentity(username: "Spartacus", roles: new List<string> { "Spartan" }, datasets: new List<string> { "datasetId" }) });`.

Note that username, roles and dataset are all required.

Using this approach, even if the user does manipulate the JavaScript to get the report in edit mode, they will not be able to access data filtered out by your DAX statements.

Comment: That's true, but I'm more concerned about the underlying data being made visible through the edit function. I would like to build multiple reports off of one common dataset which I filter (according to client, user, etc.). Then any changes to the data model only need to be made once. It is also more efficient with space. But if the user can easily edit the JavaScript and change the filters, then there's no real data protection.

Comment: You can achieve data protection using Row-Level-Security by user, instead of regular filters... That way the user would only see the data available to him, regardless of 'hacking' the JS to see it.

Comment: A couple of points from my testing: (1) it's not necessary to define the username anywhere beforehand (I assume it's logged somewhere), (2) the roles are defined for the dataset not the report, so any new reports that are subsequently created using the same dataset as source can apply the same roles automatically.